# Do I still need a package-lock.json if I am not using caret(^) or tilde(~) in my package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

If I am always using definite versions of packages inside my package.json, what is the need of package-lock.json. Or other way to put this question is , If someone wants to use package-lock.json, why can't they just use definite versions of packages(1.2.3 and not  ^1.2.3) inside package.json.

Comment: child package versions could still vary, couldn't they?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Comment: Take a look into the generated `package-json`. If it contains only the packages you listed in `package.json` then you probably don't need it. Otherwise you definitely need it because it locks the dependencies of your dependencies to some versions you cannot control otherwise.

Comment: @imjared If that is the case then you answered my question. I was under the impression that it is only for packages in my package.json. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `package-lock.json` optimize the installation process because the full dependency tree is already calculated :

> optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.
>   [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json#description)

And as @imjared mentionned, definite versions of package can still have dependencies on caret versions.